# How to record Mod_Date_Time in MS ACCESS

Tags: forms, datetime, ms-access

I have many forms in my database for which I've been able to capture a CREATE_DATE_TIME for each record in each table. Is there a way to also capture the MOD_DATE_TIME for each record? I.e. capture when the last time was that the record was modified?

Comment: In each of your update statements, just add the `MOD_DATE_TIME` column and use the `Now()` function to grab the current date and time.

Comment: can you write the code out?

Comment: It depends on how you are updating your database... ad-hoc queries or Recordset.Update?

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question. Im simply looking for code to update a mod_date_time on close of a record in the form using the beforeupdate function

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of `MOD_DATE_TIME` in the `BeforeUpdate` event of the form - just like you already for `CREATE_DATE_TIME` in the `BeforeInsert` event.